# In a dos batch file, can IF "%a%"=="%b%" (goto :label1) else goto :label2, be rewritten to read only one label?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I would like the script to continue to the next line if a & b are equal, without having to do a `goto :label1`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it the other way round:

```
IF NOT "%a%"=="%b%" goto label2
::the label1 stuff
```

So if a and b are equal, the label2 goto won't run, and it will process the label1 stuff

Comment: may be before `:label2` there should be `goto :eof` or `goto :lablel3` to avoid execution of `:label2`